# Como parar un setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo parar un `setTimeout`, mientras está ejecutandose, pensé que era con `clearTimeout`, pero no es así

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);

function main() {
    var mano = document.getElementById("mano");
    mano.style.left = document.body.scrollWidth-40 + "px";
    mano.style.top = (document.body.scrollHeight-40) + "px";
     mano.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if(th) {
            clearTimeout(th); // <- TERMINAR SET TIMEOUT
        }
    });
    function titulohome() {
        var title = document.getElementById("hometitle");
        var msg_listos = [];
        var astrocosmos = "Esta web se basará".split(''),
            i = 0,
            ac = astrocosmos.length;

        /*  ------------------------------ */
        /* Titulo Bienvenido */ 
        var titulo = "Bienvenido".split(''),
            j = 0,
            l = titulo.length;
        var a = document.createElement("AUDIO");
        a.src = "tc.mp3";
        var veces = 0,
            veces2 = 0;
        var tiempoUsado = 0;
        var conocimiento = "En un instrumento para mejorar el conocimiento en diferentes ciencias importantes.".split(''),
            u = 0,
            ul = conocimiento.length;
        for (; j < l; j++) {
            (function () {
                var self = j;
                a.autoplay = true;
                a.load();
                window.ab1 = a1;
                var a1 = setTimeout(function () {
                    if (self == 9) a.pause();
                    title.innerHTML += titulo[self];
                    title.style.position = "absolute";
                    var actualW = title.clientWidth;
                    var actualH = title.clientHeight;
                    title.style.left = (document.body.offsetWidth - actualW) / 2 + "px";
                    title.style.top = (document.body.scrollHeight + 50 - actualH) / 2 + "px";
                    tiempoUsado += 100 * self;
                    var a2= setTimeout(function () {
                        veces += 1;
                        if (veces == 1) {
                            title.innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        /* ----------------------- */
                        /* Base */
                        for (; i < ac; i++) {
                            (function () {
                                var closure = i;
                                var a3 = setTimeout(function () {
                                    a.play();
                                    if (closure == astrocosmos.length - 1) {
                                        a.pause();
                                    }
                                    var tiempo = (astrocosmos.length - 1) * 150;
                                    var a4= setTimeout(function () {
                                        veces2 += 1;
                                        if (veces2 == 1) title.innerHTML = "";
                                        /* -------------- Conocimiento --------------- */

                                        for (; u < ul; u++) {
                                            var v = 0;
                                            (function () {
                                                var t = u;
                                                var a5 = setTimeout(function () {
                                                    a.play();
                                                    var tiempo2 = (conocimiento.length - 1) * 150;
                                                    var a6 = setTimeout(function () {
                                                        v += 1;
                                                        title.innerHTML = "";
                                                        if(v == 1) homeEsferas("acerca", 150, 200);
                                                        function homeEsferas(idd, x, y) {
                                                            var b = document.createElement("DIV");
                                                            b.id = idd;
                                                            b.style.borderRadius = "50%";
                                                            b.style.position = "absolute";
                                                            b.style.left = parseInt(x) + "px";
                                                            b.style.top = parseInt(y) + "px";
                                                            b.style.opacity = "0.75%";
                                                            b.setAttribute("style", "background-color:white;width:400px;height:300px");
                                                            document.body.appendChild(b);
                                                        }
                                                    }, tiempo2 * 1.15);
                                                    title.style.position = "absolute";
                                                    var actualW = title.clientWidth;
                                                    var actualH = title.clientHeight;
                                                    title.style.left = (document.body.offsetWidth - actualW) / 2 + "px";
                                                    title.style.top = (document.body.scrollHeight + 50 - actualH) / 2 + "px";
                                                    title.style.fontSize = "60px";
                                                    if (t == ul - 1) a.pause();
                                                    if (t >= 24) {
                                                        title.style.marginLeft += t * 2 + "px";
                                                    }
                                                    title.innerHTML += conocimiento[t];

                                                }, 150 * t);
                                            })();
                                        }
                                        /* ------------------------------------------- */
                                    }, tiempo * 1.15); /* Borro el texto de base */
                                    title.innerHTML += astrocosmos[closure]; /* Agrego el texto */
                                    title.style.position = "absolute";
                                    var actualW = title.clientWidth;
                                    var actualH = title.clientHeight;
                                    title.style.left = (document.body.offsetWidth - actualW) / 2 + "px";
                                    title.style.top = (document.body.scrollHeight + 50 - actualH) / 2 + "px";
                                }, 150 * i);
                            })();
                        }
                    }, 5000 - tiempoUsado);
                    /* ----------------------- */
                }, 150 * self);
            })();
        }
        /* ----------------------------- */



    }

    var th = setTimeout(titulohome, 500);
    

}
```

```css
/* General */

body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#hometitle {
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

#mano {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}


/* ------- */


/* 1.0 - Menu de navegación */

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    min-width: calc(100%/5);
    /* Cantidad de li */
}

#menu li:first-child a {
    background-color: gray;
}

#menu li a {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}


/* ------------------------- */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Astro cosmos</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="application/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
   <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="home.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="maths.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
    <li><a href="physics.html">Física</a></li>
    <li><a href="computacion.html">Computación</a></li>
    <li><a href="others.html">Otros</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img id="mano" src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mikadzuki/images/6/6c/Mano.png/revision/latest?cb=20140428125615&path-prefix=es" alt="Detener Inicio"\>
  <i id="hometitle"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

***Pensé que era de esta manera pero no me funcionó***

***En las primeras lineas de la función `main` intento parar el timeout cuando se da click en la imagen que es un mano***

Comment: Sera porque la variable `milisegundos`  no esta definida?

Comment: Sería mejor con un ejemplo ya funcional, o tu código que te esté generando problemas, porque en efecto la manera de detenerlo sería con `clearTimeout()`

Comment: Listo mi ejemplo funcional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si funciona pero creo que no es como esperas.

Para empezar la mano que debe de tener el time out se mueve y se oculta, pero bueno supongo que es por que es un demo.

setTimeout ejecuta una función despues de haber pasado cierto tiempo, en tu caso ejecutas `titulohome` despues de 500 milisegundos

```
var th = setTimeout(titulohome, 500);
```

clearTimeout detiene esa funcion **antes** de que inicie (antes de tus 500 ms), una vez que se ejecuto `titulohome` no importa cuantas veces presiones "mano" pues ya se ejecuto la función.

Intenta poniendolo en 3000 (3 segundos) y presiona "mano", veras que nunca se ejecuta `titulohome`

```
var th = setTimeout(titulohome, 3000);
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero y cual es la solución?

Comment: Detenerlos con clearTimeout va a ser algo dificil ya que se van desencadenando uno a uno y no sabes cual está activo a la hora de hacer el click en detener. Yo creo que lo mas práctico es declarar una variable global `var animacion = true;` y en cuanto presionen detener ponerla en `false`, en cada funcion de los time out validar si es `false` no continue animando y que no desencadene otras animaciones. Y lo ideal sería que te ayudaras de un plugin especializado en animaciones